# xpath query no results

Tags: java, xpath

My xpath query does not work and I can not find a solution for hours. I am thankful for every help.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8")));
Document xmldocument = db.parse(inputSource);
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String prefix = xmldocument.getDocumentElement().getPrefix();
searchElementsXml = new String[]{"name", "id", "version", "description", "keywords", "authorInfos.name", "status"};

for(int j = 0; j < searchElementsXml.length; j++){
   String expression ="/*/" + prefix + ":" + searchElementsXml[j];
   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) 
   xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmldocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                                    
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
      }
}
```

Part of the previous attempts for expression:

```
String expression ="/*/" + prefix + ":" + searchElementsXml[j];
String expression ="/*:serviceSpecification" "/*:" + searchElementsXml[j];
String expression ="/*/*:id"
```

They work on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output but not in my java code.

My XML look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceSpecificationSchema:serviceSpecification xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ServiceSpecificationSchema="http://foo.bar/ServiceSpecificationSchema.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://foo.barServiceSpecificationSchema.xsd ServiceSpecificationSchema.xml">
    <ServiceSpecificationSchema:id>someid</ServiceSpecificationSchema:id>
    <ServiceSpecificationSchema:name>myname</ServiceSpecificationSchema:name>
....
```

Comment: Btw you have a error in the example xml - name element closed by version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error occurred while copying the part and is not present in the original code. I'm adjusting it.

Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have aded the following lines:

```
SimpleNamespaceContext simpleNamespaceContext = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
                        simpleNamespaceContext.bindNamespaceUri(prefix,uri);
                        xPath.setNamespaceContext(simpleNamespaceContext);
```

Absolutely no idea why this is working, but now my queries work.

Comment: Because the elements exist in the namespace they're defined in, and you need to qualify them as such.

Answer (score 0):

In general it depends on underling XPath engine and XPath version you use, but actually:

`String expression ="/*/" + prefix + ":" + searchElementsXml[j];`

will not return results if `prefix` does not match namespace URI set in NamespaceContext. So after you set it up - it works.

`String expression ="/*:serviceSpecification" "/*:" + searchElementsXml[j];`

as well as

`String expression ="/*/*:id"`

both defines that `serviceSpecification` and `id` (or `searchElementsXml[j]`) must be retrieved for any namespaces. - that belongs to XPath engine and version - if it is supported then it works.

Note: XPath 1.0 does not support "any namespace" as `/*:element`. XPath 2+ does.
So, perhaps engine you use threats your XPath expression as XPath 1.0